# Full submenu not displaying in wordpress

Tags: menus

I am using Maco theme.I have added 5 submenu item.But when i hover on the parent menu item only one is being shown.

PFB my website url:- http://blythehealth.com/

In this the services menu has 5 submenus.But only one is being shown on hover.Please help ASAP.

Comment: It is a problem with your theme, you should contact their support

Comment: The theme document says the following:-
The theme supports two levels of drop-down, so you can manage your menu items and allow for deeper navigation. This theme also have two menu in header. You just need to check the box of "Theme Locations" at the menu settings.

Do u know any solution for this?

Comment: I don't know a solution. The elements are in the HTML, it is just the JS/CSS not displaying them properly. Hence you should ask their support (as they know their code best)